# Constrained Minimization of Tsallis Entropy

Tags: algorithms

I am looking for finding the velocity distribution using Principle of Maximum entropy when applied to Tsallis entropy.

Tsallis entropy is defined as:

$$
S_{T} = \frac{1}{q-1}\left(1-\int{f(p)^qdp}\right)
$$

I have the following constraints:
$$
\int{f(p)dp}=1\\
\int{pf(p)dp}=0\\
\int{p^2f(p)dp}=1\\
\int{p^3f(p)dp}=0\\
$$

Using these constraints and incorporating Lagrange multipliers, the equation of ${S_{T}}$ becomes:

$$
S_{T} = \frac{1}{q-1}\left(1-\int{f(p)^qdp}\right) + \lambda_0 \left(\int{f(p)dp}-1\right) + \lambda_1 \left(\int{pf(p)dp}\right) + \lambda_2 \left(\int{p^2f(p)dp-1}\right)+ \lambda_3 \left(\int{p^3f(p)dp}\right)
$$

Taking variation of ${S_{T}}$ with respect to ${f(p)}$ and equating it to 0, the distribution function becomes:
$$
f(p)=\left[\left(\frac{q-1}{q}\right)\left(\lambda_0+\lambda_1p+\lambda_2p^2+\lambda_3p^3\right)\right]^{\frac{1}{q-1}}
$$

The entire problem then boils down to solving for the Lagrange multiplier. However, I am unable to solve this problem using Newton-Raphson. Can anyone give me some pointers as to how to proceed with solving this problem. My MATLAB Newton Raphson code incorporating first three constraints is shown below. Any help would be appreciated:

```
%Here we use Newton_Solver

clear all;
clc;


%Initial Trials
lambda(1,1) = -1.5;
lambda(2,1) = 0.0;
lambda(3,1) = 0.09;
lambda(4,1) = 0.09;

ll = -5;
ul = 5;
steps = 10000;
iter = 1500;
i = 0;
q = 1.5; %Tsallis q index
while(i<iter)
    func_val = zeros(4,1);
    Jacobian_mat = zeros(4,4);

    avg_v0 = 0.0;
    avg_v1 = 0.0;
    avg_v2 = 0.0;
    avg_v3 = 0.0;
    avg_v4 = 0.0;
    avg_v5 = 0.0;
    avg_v6 = 0.0;    
    for(j=1:steps)
        p = ll+(ul-ll)*j/steps;
        temp = (lambda(1) + lambda(2)*p + lambda(3)*p*p + lambda(4)*p*p*p)*(q-1)/q;
        temp = temp^(1/(q-1));
        temp = temp*(ul-ll)/steps;

        func_val(1) = func_val(1) + temp;
        func_val(2) = func_val(2) + temp*p;
        func_val(3) = func_val(3) + temp*p*p;
        func_val(4) = func_val(4) + temp*p*p*p;

        temp1 = lambda(1) + lambda(2)*p + lambda(3)*p*p + lambda(4)*p*p*p;
        temp1 = temp1^((2-q)/(q-1));
        temp1 = temp1*((q-1)/q)^(1/(q-1))/(q-1);
        temp1 = temp1*(ul-ll)/steps;

        avg_v0 = avg_v0 + temp1;
        avg_v1 = avg_v1 + temp1*p;
        avg_v2 = avg_v2 + temp1*p*p;
        avg_v3 = avg_v3 + temp1*p*p*p;
        avg_v4 = avg_v4 + temp1*p*p*p*p;
        avg_v5 = avg_v5 + temp1*p*p*p*p*p;
        avg_v6 = avg_v6 + temp1*p*p*p*p*p*p;

    end

    Jacobian_mat(1,1) = avg_v0;    
    Jacobian_mat(1,2) = avg_v1;   
    Jacobian_mat(1,3) = avg_v2;
    Jacobian_mat(1,4) = avg_v3;

    Jacobian_mat(2,1) = avg_v1;    
    Jacobian_mat(2,2) = avg_v2;
    Jacobian_mat(2,3) = avg_v3;
    Jacobian_mat(2,4) = avg_v5;

    Jacobian_mat(3,1) = avg_v2;    
    Jacobian_mat(3,2) = avg_v3;
    Jacobian_mat(3,3) = avg_v4;
    Jacobian_mat(3,4) = avg_v5;

    Jacobian_mat(4,1) = avg_v3;    
    Jacobian_mat(4,2) = avg_v4;
    Jacobian_mat(4,3) = avg_v5;
    Jacobian_mat(4,4) = avg_v6;

    func_val(1) = func_val(1) - 1.0;
    func_val(2) = func_val(2) - 0.0;
    func_val(3) = func_val(3) - 1.0;
    func_val(4) = func_val(4) - 0.0;

    Jacobian_inv = Jacobian_mat^(-1);
    lambda = lambda - Jacobian_inv*func_val*1.0;

    Disp_val = ['Step is: ',num2str(i), ' Lambda 1 values:', num2str(lambda(1,1))];
    Disp_val1 = ['Step is: ',num2str(i), ' Lambda 2 values:', num2str(lambda(2,1))];
    Disp_val2 = ['Step is: ',num2str(i), ' Lambda 3 values:', num2str(lambda(3,1))];
    Disp_val3 = ['Step is: ',num2str(i), ' Lambda 4 values:', num2str(lambda(4,1))];
    Disp_val4 = ['Step is: ',num2str(i), ' AVG 1 values:', num2str(func_val(1) + 1.0)];
    Disp_val5 = ['Step is: ',num2str(i), ' AVG 2 values:', num2str(func_val(2) + 0.0)];
    Disp_val6 = ['Step is: ',num2str(i), ' AVG 3 values:', num2str(func_val(3) + 1.0)];
    Disp_val7 = ['Step is: ',num2str(i), ' AVG 4 values:', num2str(func_val(4) + 0.0)];

    disp(Disp_val);
    disp(Disp_val1);
    disp(Disp_val2);
    disp(Disp_val3);
    disp(Disp_val4);
    disp(Disp_val5);
    disp(Disp_val6);
    disp(Disp_val7);
    disp(' ');
    i = i+1;
end
```

Comment: I don't see how this is the equation for $f(p)$. Please edit your question so that it shows the Lagrangian, the optimality condition, and how you arrive at your statement. A clear exposition will likely show you where to go next.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. It was carelessness on my part. I have changed the information and made new additions as you had suggested. I request you to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want to maximize the entropy, so after the exposition you've presented above, you have something like:

\begin{align}
\min_{\lambda_{0}, \ldots, \lambda_{3}} -\frac{1}{q - 1}\left(1-\int{\left[\left(\frac{q-1}{q}\right)\left(\lambda_0+\lambda_1p+\lambda_2p^2+\lambda_3p^3\right)\right]^{\frac{q}{q-1}}dp}\right)
\end{align}

and you want to do unconstrained minimization. Here, I'm using the fact that most optimization problems are posed as minimization problems, and $\max_{x} g(x) = \min_{x} -g(x)$.

The big comments I'd make about your code are:

- **Don't do Newton's method (for equation solving) by hand, if you can help it.** People mess it up, and library routines are much more robust when it comes to setting convergence tolerances. MATLAB includes it in the `fsolve` routine as part of the Optimization Toolbox. You may not have that toolbox (toolboxes are expensive, so individuals and institutions don't necessarily have them), in which case, I'd encourage you to find another tool that does (Python definitely does, Octave might).
- **Don't do Newton's method (for unconstrained optimization) by hand, for the same reasons.** MATLAB includes this routine, again, as part of the Optimization Toolbox. You can call it via `fminunc`. Mistakes made in numerical algorithms can be very subtle, and affect your results in a profound way. Using libraries is a big time saver by eliminating another source of error.
- **Generally speaking, don't calculate the explicit inverse of a matrix.** Set up and solve an equivalent linear system. In MATLAB, use the backslash operator for this purpose.
- **If convergence is a problem and you have to write Newton's method by hand, consider building in something like a line search for robustness, and add some error tolerance checks, so you don't necessarily have to run all 1500 iterations.** These features are generally included in a library, so like I said, get access to one rather than write these yourself (which is another source of error, and time-consuming).
- **Vectorize your evaluation of the integrals. For that matter, vectorize all your function evaluations, if possible.** You're explicitly looping over everything, and constructing arrays element-by-element. These processes are slow, because you can't take advantage of any of the fast MATLAB routines that are linked from compiled libraries.
- **Modularize your code.** You should be able to move your objective function, gradient, and Hessian evaluations into their own functions (or maybe a combined function that calculates two or three of these quantities, if you want to reuse information from the integration). Refactoring your code in this way would make it much easier to read and test.
- **Make your code self-documenting.** Add comments judiciously. People will spend more time reading your code than it takes for you to write it. It's hard to go through parts of your code because I have no clue what `avg_v0` is supposed to mean, other than, well, it's some sort of average. If your main audience is someone in your application area, maybe this sort of naming is fine. You've posted your code to a general computational science message board, so I encourage you to make it accessible to general computational scientists. I have no idea what `temp` means either, other than it's a temporary variable.
- **Test your code.** If you've made your code modular, you should be able to test it in an automated way using unit tests. MATLAB xUnit is a good library for this purpose; later versions of MATLAB have unit testing functionality built in. You should be able to construct examples with values of $q$ and $\lambda_{i}$, $i = 0, \ldots, 3$ so that you can check evaluations of your objective function, gradient, and Hessian against values you can compute by hand analytically. You could also use a computer algebra system like Maple, Mathematica, Sage, or SymPy for this purpose (and in the process, actually derive your gradient and Hessian functions, mitigating another source of error: bad math). Testing means writing more code, but it also means debugging is easier, because you have more diagnostics with which to find errors, and a more systematic means of identifying these errors.
- **Look at [Software Carpentry](http://software-carpentry.org/)**, which discusses a lot of the points on testing, modularization, self-documenting code, etc. (*Disclaimer:* I do some volunteer work for Software Carpentry.)